# error: constructor SpotsDialog in class SpotsDialog cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: android

I am using this code
and getting the error

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        AccountKitLoginResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);
        if (result.getError() != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" +result.getError().getErrorType().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (result.wasCancelled())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "cancel"  ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (result.getAccessToken() !=null)
            {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setMessage("plz wait");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

error: constructor SpotsDialog in class SpotsDialog cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String,int,boolean,OnCancelListener
found: MainActivity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
????????????

Answer (score 0):

More like a hack but downgrading from 1.1 to 0.7 solved the issue for me

```
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With  implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
Use below code
lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog

alertDialog = SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).build()
```

Comment: It would help if you explain how this code solves the problem.